# Meaning of にかかっている in this sentence

Tags: meaning, verbs

In this sentence(from this site:http://aozora-pwresult.com/archives/4924):

> このリストはオーエンズにかかっているんだ。

I don't know how to interpret Noun(personal name) + に + かかっている.

I've been looking at www.imabi.net/l243kakarukakeru.htm and I think it could mean this:

> 28. "To be concerned", "be the work of", or "to concern". Only a usage of 係る.

So, could this sentence mean: "This リスト is going to be about オーエンズ?

Also, I found this example sentence with it's translation:

> 成果は君の努力にかかっている。(The outcome will depend on your efforts.)

So, could it also mean: "This list will depend on(be in charge of) オーエンズ"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognize the latter understanding is correct, where かかっている is used as "depends on".